# Line between points in projective space?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I am trying to find the line through the points $(0 : 1 : 0)$ and $(1 : 1 : 1)$ in $\mathbb P^2$
and $(0 :1 : 0: 1)$ and $(1: 1: 1: 0)$ in $\mathbb P^3.$

Would the first line be the set of points $\{(b, a+b, b)\}$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb P^1$ 
and the second, $\{(d, c+d, d,c)\}$ for all $c, d \in \mathbb P^1$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can treat the *points on a line* as the set of all linear combinations of the two defining points, the way you did.

In my nomenclature, I'd usually use different vectors to describe *the line itself*. In $\mathbb P^2$ I'd use the cross product to obtain a vector normal to all the points. In $\mathbb P^3$ I'd use [Plücker coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates). But there are applications where the set of all points is more useful, so it depends.